# Counting tree nodes that end probabilistically

Tags: probability, random

Suppose we have $N$ root nodes that can branch into $N$ new nodes every level. There is a maximum of 64 levels. However, on any given step, each node has a chance $P$ of terminating. What is the expected value of $S$, the total number of nodes in the tree?

Is the answer simply

$$S = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{63}(1-P)^n *N^n  $$

or something like that? This is similar to other questions on here such as [Expected number of leaf nodes resulting from branching process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437617/expected-number-of-leaf-nodes-resulting-from-branching-process) or [expected value tree structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380556/expected-value-tree-structure?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Each level should be expected to contain $C[N(1-P)]$ nodes, where $C$ is the number of nodes on the previous level. This is because every $C$ that survives, which is $C(1-P)$ on average, multiplies to $N$ more nodes. Thus the expected total, $S$ is indeed

$$S = N\sum\limits_{n=0}^{63} \left[N(1-P)\right]^n$$